Program not Running --- Error -- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
I am run my java code in IntelliJ it is showing this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class CWA_01_INTRO Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CWA_01_INTRO

whereas the same code is running in vs code, I am looking for your affirmative help.
I have asked some chatgpt , pieces copilot but not getting a summarize solution, rather than list of causes.
Here is my code
import java.util.*;
public class CWA_01_INTRO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner as = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello World ");
       
        as.close();
    }
}


Post entire error message. Don’t make us guess!

Post details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

Mark src as Sources Root: Right-click on the src folder, select Mark Directory as → Sources Root.
Check Run Configuration: Go to the run configuration dropdown, select Edit Configurations, and ensure Main class is set to CWA_01_INTRO.
Rebuild the Project: Go to Build → Rebuild Project.
Check Output Path: In File → Project Structure, verify the output path is correct.
Invalidate Caches: Go to File → Invalidate Caches / Restart, and choose Invalidate and Restart.

thanks for your answer but in project structure I made my folder as source file then program is running just to confirm I have to make every folder as source file or make parent folder as source file.
